# Transpose partialialy Matched data from row to columns

Tags: r

I have a master column that looks like this:

`CompanyName
 Google
 Tesco`

I also have another data frame that looks like this:

`CompanyVariationsNames
 google plc
 tesco bank
 tesco insurance
 google finance
 google play`

I need the data to look like this:

`Company Name     Variation1    Variation2       Variation3
 Google           google plc    google finance   google play
 Tesco            tesco bank    tesco insurance`

this is just a sample as i have 750 company names that have returned about 5000 company name variations.
i have managed to get all the matching customer variations in one column with the below code as the `CompanyVariationsNames` column comes from a pool of of over 100k company names:

`matched1 = subset(DF, grepl(paste(Set1, collapse = "|"), DF$Customer_Name, ignore.case = T ))` but i cant find a way to make them look like the above mentioned result.
any advice would be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be

```r
library(dplyr)
library(splitstackshape)

df2 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(CompanyName = ifelse(is.null(as.character(Filter(length, 
                                           lapply(df1$CompanyName, function(x) x[grepl(x, CompanyVariationsNames, ignore.case=T)])))),
                              NA,
                              as.character(Filter(length, 
                                                  lapply(df1$CompanyName, function(x) x[grepl(x, CompanyVariationsNames, ignore.case=T)]))))) %>%
  filter(!is.na(CompanyName)) %>%
  group_by(CompanyName) %>%
  summarise(Variation = paste(CompanyVariationsNames, collapse=",")) %>%
  cSplit("Variation", ",")
```

**Output is:**

```
   CompanyName Variation_1     Variation_2 Variation_3
1:      Google  google plc  google finance google play
2:       Tesco  tesco bank tesco insurance          NA
```

**Sample data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(CompanyName = c("Google", "Tesco")), .Names = "CompanyName", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

df2 <- structure(list(CompanyVariationsNames = c("google plc", "tesco bank", 
"tesco insurance", "google finance", "google play")), .Names = "CompanyVariationsNames", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

**Update:** Added logic to handle below error

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column "CompanyName" must be
>   length 1 (the group size), not 0

Comment: This works if you create the data frames manually. the thing is that i use the read.csv function to import large data sets (750 and 5k rows) is there a way to use your criteria but with a csv file?

Comment: Can you be more specific please? I think this might be handy - `df <- read.csv("path/file_name.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)`

Comment: the DF1 dataset has a col called  `CustomerName` and it has 425 company names. the DF2 has a col called `CompanyVariationsNames` and it contains 54k comapny names that are variations of the DF1 company names. when i apply the code from your answer i get the error mantioned above but if i create the DFs and enter the company names manually (not all the names of course!) then the code works perfectly!

Comment: Seems you forgot to mention the error message :) BTW what happens when you use `read.csv` code I mentioned in my previous comment? Doesn't that help? If you can help me with `dput(head(df1))` & `dput(head(df2))` then I would be in a better position to assist you.

Comment: when i did the amendments that you recommended it didnt do anything. output of DF1: 
`structure(list(CompanyName = c("THUS LTD", "VIRGIN", "FIREFIGHTERS", 
"GLOBAL MARINE", "NEW VOICE MEDIA", "NUS")), .Names = "CompanyName", row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")`


output of DF2:

`structure(list(CompanyVariationsNames = c("   232_299_2067", 
"   235_0_0", "   __", " (THUS RESELLER)  VIROCOM LTD", " (THUS RESELLER) A ONE FEED SUPPLEMENTS LIMITED", 
" (THUS RESELLER) ARROW ELECTRONICS LTD")), .Names = "CompanyVariationsNames", row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: it looks like not all the companies have been listed in the data fame? i should have 425 for DF1 and 54k for DF2?

Comment: and the error message is:

`Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column "CompanyName" must be length 1 (the group size), not 0`